# Wayback Machine API parameters

Tags: java, php

Wayback machine offers an API allowing you to download information. There are actually multiple APIs and after searching for a few hours I really can't manage to do the following:

Using the wayback machine API, I am trying to get  **a list of all domains indexed on 06/06/15**.

I have read the documentation here

https://archive.org/help/wayback_api.php

but I can't find it...

I expected something like this to work:

```
http://archive.org/wayback/available?url=*&timestamp=20150606
```

Comment: Why negative voting? Please let me know so I can avoid mistakes in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Downvoters expect that you'll re-read the instructions for asking good questions, and have an aha moment yourself. For example, you've got no code, yet you've tagged two languages, implying you want an answer with code. You say you've read documentation, and provided a link to it, but the documentation clearly says that the JSON API tests a *given url*; the `*` is not a [valid URL](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt). The same single page of documentation goes on to describe the _Wayback CDX Server API_, which is for "more in depth information". This indicates a lack of research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example check it bellow:

http://archive.org/wayback/available?http://sourceforge.net/projects/=%27+url+%27&timestamp=20131006000000

Make sure you have the correct timestamp value

These are the lines i used to generate urls. It's in python:

```
url = "http://sourceforge.net/projects/"+name.rstrip()

wbm_url = 'http://archive.org/wayback/available?url='+url+'&timestamp=20131006000000'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am looking to get a list of all sites indexed by the wayback machine on a specific date. Your code get's a list of the pages on a specific domain on a specific date.

Comment: I don't think sourceforge has public api that supports that. You can email them and ask. But it's a long shot.

Comment: Try their cdx server if you haven't. https://github.com/internetarchive/wayback/tree/master/wayback-cdx-server

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to do what you want (?url=*), by design. You're asking us to go through 36 terabytes of data to fish out a huge list; it's not a query that our query engine supports.

Comment: @greg-indahl is there an API call to return a list of saved timestamps for a given url? The API supports fetching a specific archived version by timestamp, but I couldn't find a way to see the timestamps.

Comment: Yes, please read the documentation. You can fetch all timestamps for a domain, or for an url.

    curl "http://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx?url=www.pbm.com/~lindahl/" | wc -l

returns 492 timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

Since 2013, there may be an answer on how to get the timestamps one would need in order to fetch a specific archived copy of a website. look at this link:

http://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx?url=archive.org&limit=5&showResumeKey=true

Explained here:

https://github.com/internetarchive/wayback/tree/master/wayback-cdx-server#advanced-usage

Then, to get confirmation this url works (using python's requests):

`w = requests.get('http://archive.org/wayback/available?url=archive.org&timestamp=997121112295')`

Or you can fetch the HTML directly:

`w2 = requests.get('http://web.archive.org/web/20040324162136/http://www.globalgiving.org:80/')`